# design patterns for python generator/iterator? (backwad read/total count)

Tags: python, asynchronous, iterator, cursor, generator

I am writing a python interface which basically construct from a db row by row, send the stream to a tcp socket, another thread checkes the tcp response and decide if there's an error response, skip certain steams and retry from earlier ones.

Pseudo-code below, PK means PrimaryKey.

It's basically like this

```
def generate_msg(pk_start, pk_stop):
    for x in db.query(pk>pk_startand pk<pk_stop):
        yield pack_to_stream(x)
```

then the tcp socket send thread is like:

```
for msg in generate_msg(first_id, last_id):
    socket.send(msg)
```

The problem is when the tcp socket `read` thread finds some error in response, the msg's pk is returned, so I need to restart the iterator from the `pk`

So here's my question:

1. what's the design parttern for a iterator which can move both forward and backward, esp. working with database row cursors
2. can I get the total count of an iterator in the first place without reading the whole list?
3. What's the general advice for my scenario?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterators are designed to save memory by dealing with one item at a time, and can potentially produce an unlimited number of items. As a result of their design however, you usually cannot know their length without consuming the whole iterator, and you are normally not expected to be able to steer them.

That said, there is nothing stopping you from making a custom class that can be used both as an iterator and can provide additional functionality. Database cursors are the canonical example of such a class; the cursor can be iterated over to yield rows, but you can also ask it for a rowcount (so the length of the sequence), and get additional information about columns, get multiple rows, or point to a new result set by calling the `.execute()` method.

If you want to build a custom class that acts as an iterator, you need to give it a [`__iter__()` method](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__iter__). You either make this method into a generator (by using the `yield` statement), or just `return self` and give your class a [`.next()` method](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#iterator.next); the latter is expected to return one item (do not use `yield`), or raise [`StopIteration`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.StopIteration) when no more items can be returned.

You can then add other methods that return length information, or re-set the query to start from a given primary key.

Untested, python-ish code:

```
class MessagesIterator(object):
    def __init__(self, pk_start, pk_stop):
        self.pk_start, self.pk_stop = pk_start, pk_stop
        self.cursor = db.query("pk>? and pk<?", (pk_start, pk_stop))

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def next(self):
        return next(self.cursor)  # raises StopIteration when done

    def length(self):
        return self.cursor.rowcount

    def move_to(self, pk_start):
        # Validate pk_start perhaps
        self.pk_start = pk_start
        self.cursor = db.query("pk>? and pk<?", (self.pk_start, self.pk_stop))
```

Comment: Thanks! So each move_to() will cause another db read, right? Anyway to minimize that?

Comment: @est: You could include a buffering scheme, keep the last `n` rows stored on the instance and start yielding from the buffer when you move back. It's up to you how complex you want to make this.